# Handling of enter key in an HTML5 dialog

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dialog, modal-dialog

I've implemented an HTML5 dialog, and as long as the user interacts with the buttons (which emit "close" events), it works fine.

But suppose you press the Enter key. The dialog also closes. I've discovered that the dialog also intercepts keyboard events directly, and close the dialog automatically. This bypasses my processing code.

I can't figure out how to intercept the keyboard event, nor is it clear at what level of the DOM is the the event intercepted and handled.  Putting a 'keyup' or similar listener on the dialog does not seem to get the event.

Where are keyboard events intercepted by default when a dialog is in "on" state, and how do I get at them?

Comment: the keyup might be a delegate on document rather than the modal

Comment: @Kinglish: you mean that the event would ultimately get to the document? As a test, I put a listener on document. I don't get a response on 'keyup' on either the dialog or the document. I'll try the body, since I'm using Vue and "teleported" the dialog under the body.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I understand the behavior.

In order to test my dialog, I had a button with the text of "Dialog". The click handler on this button toggles whether the dialog displays or not.

So, I press the Dialog button, and the dialog displays.

*But*: even though the button is hidden by the modal dialog, it turns out that this button *still* has focus. So the enter key is handled by the (currently hidden) Dialog button, and not the dialog, nor either of the two buttons in the dialog.  Since the click handler of the Dialog button toggles the display state of the dialog, the dialog is dismissed by *that* handler.

Fix is to cause the correct button from the dialog to have focus, so an Enter key press will cause the correct action.